# How do I open cans?

Tags: die2nite

Our town is short on food, with increasingly large pile of canned food in the bank, but no way to open them. I'm only aware of two ways to open cans:

1. Open the can with a screwdriver.
2. Open the can with a can opener.

Nobody in our town has found one of these yet. **Are there any other ways?**

Comment: Related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/11529/why-is-this-workshop-so-important/11532#11532

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also open a can by having a Workshop in town.